# Javascript JSON pull wont iterate properly?

Tags: javascript, json

so i have this code:

```
var input=require('./task.json');
const _ = require(`underscore`);
var dps = [];
for(var element in input) {
    for (var i=0;i>dps.length;i++){
        if(dps[i].Technician===input[element].Technician){
            console.log("name already exists");
            dps[i].count=dps[i].Count+1;

        }

    }
    dps.push({Technician: input[element].Technician, Count:0});
}


  console.log(dps);
```

and my task.json file looks like this:

```
{{
        "TaskID": 35708,
        "TaskDate": "2011-06-20T00:00:00",
        "Technician": "UCH - Billy Metcalf"
    },
{
        "TaskID": 35708,
        "TaskDate": "2011-06-19T00:00:00",
        "Technician": "Edward F. Dawson"
    }
}
```

when i run my file using node on my data.js file i get a return that looks like this:

```
[{Technician:'UCH - Billy Metcalf',Count:0},
{Technician:'Edward F. Dawson',Count:0}]
```

the whole point is soo that instead of having a count always be zero i want it to go through the json file and if it finds that a json file already exists in my new variable dps to increase the count and keep my new array dps distinct with no repeating names so for example if there is 5 "Edward F. Dawson" then the

```
{Technician:'Edward F. Dawson',Count:5}
```

Comment: The JSON you posted is incomplete; it's (at least) missing a `{` at the beginning. Is that all that's missing?

Comment: Also you create the object with upper-case `Count` but the code that increments it expects lower-case `count`.

Comment: sorry i copied the json file over wrong and even when i change the count to Count i still get 0;

Comment: Your `task.json` is  wrong. `{ }` is used for objects, arrays go in `[ ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The code should be self-explanatory if you walk it through.

```
var input=require('./task.json');
const _ = require(`underscore`);
var dps = [];
var found=0;
for(var element in input) {
    found=0
    for (var i=0;i>dps.length;i++){
        if(dps[i].Technician===input[element].Technician){
            console.log("name already exists");
            dps[i].count=dps[i].Count+1;
            found=1
        }

    }
    if ( found === 0){ // only if we did not find !
        dps.push({Technician: input[element].Technician, Count:1});
    }
}

  console.log(dps);
```

Comment: Try using the .some() method instead of your for loop

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid JSON in your `task.json` file. To denote an array of objects, surround the objects with **brackets**[], not curly braces{}.

Once you get your JSON into an array, you will be able to run the following code:

```
var input = require('./task.json');
const _ = require(`underscore`);
var dps = [];
input.forEach(function (element) {
    var found = dps.some(function (elem) {
      if (elem.Technician === element.Technician) {
          elem.Count = elem.Count + 1;
          return true;
      }
    });
    if (!found) {
      dps.push({Technician: element.Technician, Count: 1});
    }
});

console.log(dps);
```

Optionally, you can go for a more functional approach if that's more your taste by using `.reduce()`

```
var dps = input.reduce(function (arr, currElem) {
    var found = arr.some(function (elem) {
      if (elem.Technician === currElem.Technician) {
          elem.Count = elem.Count + 1;
          return true;
      }
    });
    if (!found) {
      arr.push({Technician: currElem.Technician, Count: 1});
    }
    return arr;
}, []);

console.log(dps);
```

#### Here's the code in action:

```js
var input = [{
  "TaskID": 35708,
  "TaskDate": "2011-06-20T00:00:00",
  "Technician": "UCH - Billy Metcalf"
}, {
  "TaskID": 35708,
  "TaskDate": "2011-06-19T00:00:00",
  "Technician": "Edward F. Dawson"
}, {
  "TaskID": 35708,
  "TaskDate": "2011-06-19T00:00:00",
  "Technician": "Edward F. Dawson"
}, {
  "TaskID": 35708,
  "TaskDate": "2011-06-19T00:00:00",
  "Technician": "Edward F. Dawson"
}, ];
var dps = input.reduce(function (arr, currElem) {
    var found = arr.some(function (elem) {
      if (elem.Technician === currElem.Technician) {
          elem.Count = elem.Count + 1;
          return true;
      }
    });
    if (!found) {
      arr.push({Technician: currElem.Technician, Count: 1});
    }
    return arr;
}, []);

console.log(dps);
```